# missing image while loading custom svg icon in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am loading a custom marker in leaflet according to the documentation here:

http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html

My specific syntax is:

```
var imagepath = "/public/marker.svg";
myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: imagepath,
});

newMarker = L.marker([41.7998, -87.5949], {
  icon: myIcon,
}).addTo(map);
```

This actually works fine.  The marker renders as I would expect it to.  The problem is that for a brief second the marker icon renders the missing image icon [?] (presumably while it is loading).  Is there any way to supress the rendering of the missing image icon while the SVG is loading?  I am using Firefox 30.0 and Leaflet 0.7.3.

Comment: In theory you could load the image beforehand in the browser, so that it will be cached. Then create the leaflet icons. Note that this implies you're using a modern browser, and setting the caching flag on the back-end that is serving the assets (this will let return a `HTTP 304` for each following request)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I agree something like this may work, although this kind of a hack.  I'd prefer something more elegant if possible (i.e. applying CSS styles).  One of the things I was considering futzing around with are SVG sprites or embedding the information somehow in a stylesheet as base64 encoded data.  I'm still working on this problem, I'll report back if I come up with anything respectable.